# Asynchronous property setter

Tags: python, async-await

Let us suppose we have a class with a property that can only be set asynchronously. Is there a way to make this work without explicitly calling a setter?

MNWE:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class AsyncTest:
    def __init__(self, attrib):
        self._attrib = attrib

    @property
    def attrib(self):
        return self._attrib

    @attrib.setter
    async def set_attrib(self, attrib):
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        self._attrib = attrib


async def main():
    t = AsyncTest(1)
    print(t.attrib)
    await t.attrib = 3
    print(t.attrib)

asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

This fails with

```
  File "asyncprop.py", line 22
    await t.attrib = 3
       ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to await expression
```

which is not surprising, given that the grammar for `await` is

```
await ::=  ["await"] primary
```

So it seems we are bound to forget this nice `@property` and resign ourselves to using getters and setters for asynchronous operations. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't nest a statement inside another statement; assignment is a statement, and so is `await`. You could use `setattr()` to set attributes in an expression:

```
await setattr(t, 'attrib', 3)
```

However, a `property` wraps the setter in a way that does not support `async` methods (they are not awaitable), so you are still better off with an explicit setter method.

Comment: @Evpok: There probably is a way to create your own `async_property` descriptor.

Comment: Yeah, but it would still only work through `setattr`, which kind of defeats the purpose of having a property.

Comment: @Evpok: yes, until async assignments are added to the language you are limited to using `setattr()`. I doubt there ever will be such a feature (what would async assignment to a local or global even mean)?

Comment: Off the top of my head, `Browser.current_url = 'http://example.com'` where the assignment would also perform a http request to fetch the page but there are probably other use cases.

Comment: @Evpok: that's setting an attribute, not a global or local name. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I should have read you with more care :). Indeed, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `async-property` package: https://pypi.org/project/async-property/

Example:

```py
from async_property import async_property

class Foo:
    @async_property
    async def remote_value(self):
        return await get_remote_value()

f = Foo()
await f.remote_value
```

Comment: Note: as of async-property 0.2.1, it does not support setters.

Answer (score 1):

i was requiring something similar for my project and I ended up with this ugly syntax. Imagine a class MyClass containing the following

```
@property
async def State(self):
    return self.__State

@State.setter
async def State(self, value):
    if self.__State != value:
        previousValue = self.__State

        self.__State = value

        await someotherawaitable()

    return
```

for the getter part it is easy as you can simply

```
stateValue = await MyClassInstance.State
```

for the setter part this works

```
await MyClass.State.fset(MyClassInstance, newValue)
```